# comparison of node and nativescript runtimes

Tags: npm, nativescript

Can I run any node app under nativescript? From my point of view [nativescript](https://v7.docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/technical-overview) is a different runtime than node.js. But Node.js incorporates the Google Chrome V8 JavaScript engine as well. The only difference seems that some major functionality of nativescript app depends on core modules and plugins, which provides access to the underlying native mobile platforms.

For example if I run `npm install matrix-js-sdk` or `npm install libp2p`, then I can create and run a `ns` application with functionality of those packages in the same way as I would create a node application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two native bridges that connect the "native" and the "JavaScript" world. One for Android and one for iOS, and these two runtimes are the core of the framework enabling many of the unique features in NativeScript. These two runtimes are using different JavaScript engines - V8 for the Android runtime and JavaScriptCore for the iOS runtime. This means you can use node based library in nativescript apps. But some libraries will not work for example `crypto` which uses
`Secure random number generation` that is not supported by v8.

For more info on the issue check [this](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/8806).

For more info on how nativescript works check [this](https://v7.docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/technical-overview).

Comment: As you mentioned nativescript is one of many JavaScript programming environments, including Node.js, web browsers, Electron, V8 and more. npm includes libraries that work for all of these environments. And usually libraries built specifically for other platforms like node.js, so there is no warranty that a library which build for node.js can be used in with nativescript?

Comment: That is right! Some libraries rely on the `process` object for example `node-cbor`. The solution is to polyfill these libraries using third-party plugins.